# Deploy Bokeh App to public without Python

Tags: python, server, bokeh

I have a bokeh server app which is similar to the below code with call back functions and I have been trying to explore ways to deploy the bokeh app to any public server or html so that people even without python will be able to access the app.

Please let me know if there is a way to deploy the app to public

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Slider, TextInput
from bokeh.plotting import figure

# Set up data
N = 200
x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, N)
y = np.sin(x)
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))


# Set up plot
plot = figure(plot_height=400, plot_width=400, title="my sine wave",
              tools="crosshair,pan,reset,save,wheel_zoom",
              x_range=[0, 4*np.pi], y_range=[-2.5, 2.5])

plot.line('x', 'y', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)


# Set up widgets
text = TextInput(title="title", value='my sine wave')
offset = Slider(title="offset", value=0.0, start=-5.0, end=5.0, step=0.1)
amplitude = Slider(title="amplitude", value=1.0, start=-5.0, end=5.0, step=0.1)
phase = Slider(title="phase", value=0.0, start=0.0, end=2*np.pi)
freq = Slider(title="frequency", value=1.0, start=0.1, end=5.1, step=0.1)


# Set up callbacks
def update_title(attrname, old, new):
    plot.title.text = text.value

text.on_change('value', update_title)

def update_data(attrname, old, new):

    # Get the current slider values
    a = amplitude.value
    b = offset.value
    w = phase.value
    k = freq.value

    # Generate the new curve
    x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, N)
    y = a*np.sin(k*x + w) + b

    source.data = dict(x=x, y=y)

for w in [offset, amplitude, phase, freq]:
    w.on_change('value', update_data)


# Set up layouts and add to document
inputs = column(text, offset, amplitude, phase, freq)

curdoc().add_root(row(inputs, plot, width=800))
curdoc().title = "Sliders"
```

Comment: People have deployed Bokeh apps on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, bare AWS EC2 instances, Digital Ocean droplets, Azure instances, GCP, Heroku... It really depends on what you are familiar with and willing to pay for.